# How to include typescript output as staticwebassets in nuget package when using Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild

Tags: typescript, msbuild, nuget, .net-6.0, csproj

I have a following razor class library following files

- scripts/main.ts
- scripts/tsconfig.ts
- wwwroot/styles.css

The typescript builds fine, but when I pack the project, the javascript output is not included in the package under staticwebassets:

[image: nuget structure]

How do I properly integrate typescript with msbuild so that the generated output is included as static web assets?

---

this is my current csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
        <Authors>Liero</Authors>
        <Version>0.7.3</Version>
        <PackageTags>Blazor DataGrid</PackageTags>
        <EmbedUntrackedSources>true</EmbedUntrackedSources>
        <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TypescriptOutDir>wwwroot</TypescriptOutDir>
        <ResolveCurrentProjectStaticWebAssetsInputsDependsOn>
            TypeScriptCompile;
            $(ResolveCurrentProjectStaticWebAssetsInputsDependsOn)
        </ResolveCurrentProjectStaticWebAssetsInputsDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="4.6.4">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, I think there is a bug in Visual Studio.

If I build once after a full clean (including bin and obj), I get only my non generated assets in MyProject.staticwebassets.runtime.json

If I build twine (with clean between the 2), I get all my js files.

On a side note, not that it changes anything (I tried both), MS documentation says CompileTypeScript not TypeScriptCompile

Comment: You may also want to look at TfmSpecificPackageFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the PrepareForBuildDependsOn should be like this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PrepareForBuildDependsOn>CompileTypeScript;GetTypeScriptOutputForPublishing;$(PrepareForBuildDependsOn)</PrepareForBuildDependsOn>
    <TypescriptOutDir>wwwroot</TypescriptOutDir>
</PropertyGroup>


<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="4.6.4">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42110

Comment: The second time I run with the above I get the following error:
Two assets found targeting the same path with incompatible asset kinds
If I delete the js files first it won't happen I think it is trying to compile the js file as well as the ts file.